# row number with by in data.table

Tags: r, indexing, datatable, rank

I have this easy task to do, imagine I have this table :

```
   var1
1:    X
2:    X
3:    Y
4:    X
5:    Z
6:    Y
```

And I want to create a new variable like this :

```
   var1 nth
1:    X   1
2:    X   2
3:    Y   1
4:    X   3
5:    Z   1
6:    Y   2
```

In reality I have a lot of variables plenty of lines.
So my actual solution is (which works well) :

```
dt[, flag := 1]
dt[, nth := frank(flag, ties.method = "random"), by = .(var1)]
```

but this is slow, and I'm not really interested by ranking.(frank has to sort and rank, and I need just a simple thing which is indexing).

I imagined this solution, but doesn't work :

```
dt[, pos := .I, by = .(var1)]
```

Do you have any fast and straightforward solution for this task ?

Thank you

Comment: `rowid(var1)` or `rowidv(var1)`, i.e. `dt[, nth:=rowidv(var1)]`

Comment: `dt[, nth := 1:.N, by = var1]`

Answer (score 4):

```
dt[, nth := row.names(.SD), by = var1]
```